# average purchase

Tags: sql

[image]

how to get customer ids whose average purchase is more than 50 rupees (col.3 is purchase id and has to be aggregated per customer)

SELECT distinct customer id
from table
where average purchase of a customer is greater than 50
group by customer id

Comment: Imagine someone has two purchases. One is 100 items for 1 rupee each, and the other purchase (next day) is 1 item for 100 rupees. Is the average either a) 200 rupees/101 items = about 2 rupees per item, or b) (1 + 100)/2 = 50.5 rupees per purchase?

Comment: total no. of purchases =2 
total value of purchase = 100 + 100 = 200
I need, average = 200/2 = 100

Comment: Sorry yes - I made a mistake on the second option. You are correct in that it should have been b) (100 + 100)/2 = 100. Thanks. I think @Fahmi's answer does this.

Comment: Thanks. how to limit the average >50 but less than <70 for the same case?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT customer_id 
from table 
group by customer_id
having avg(col2)>50
```

Comment: col.3 is purchase id and has to be aggregated for a customer id

Comment: @user14263992, check now

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try. how to limit the average >50 but less than <70 for the same case?

Comment: @user14263992, condition then will be having avg(col2)>50 and avg(col2)<70